# Adding Heroes of the Fallen Lands to D&D 4e's downloadable Character Builder

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, tools, dnd-4e-character-builder

Looking to try and make some characters with the new subclasses from HotFL but found out that it wasn't put out for the downloadable WotC builder.

What's the easiest way to add the new elements?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answering it entails encouraging piracy of Wizards of the Coasts' intellectual property.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I don't think this is actually encouraging piracy. If anyone said "here, put these files / this content into your thing," and reproduced the full content, that'd be piracy. If we assume they have the book to reproduce the content themselves, and just tell them _how_ to add it to the builder (if it's possible), we're not facilitating piracy at all: I could do this with _my_ books I legally own.

Comment: Transforming material (that one has legitimate copies of) for private use isn't piracy (in most jurisdictions), so there's no legal issues with this question. (IANAL, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible with a tool of questionable legality. Some fans have made a Character Builder loader called CBLoader that allows you to load custom XML files into the Character Builder.

Given this site's discomfort regarding tools that are heavily used for piracy, I won't link to the Character Builder loader. If you own the Heroes of the Fallen Lands material, converting it probably doesn't violate copyright law, but it might violate your license to use the software or the material.

Comment: To clarify, there's no policy about tools that *could* be used for piracy (that covers way too much anyway, like text editors and browsers). We have sorta-policy of removing direct links to illegal content or posts advocating piracy, which isn't what pointing to cbloader would do. Excellent point about license violation though, so *caveat user*.

Answer (score -4):

**We can't help you**

The Downloadable character builder was essentially the beta. It was discontinued, and unsupported and since the live version launched on the D&D website. The Character Builder hosted on D&D is up to date and kept that way through D&DInsider subscriptions. Us telling you how to replicate content in it would be copyright infringement. We avoid advocating piracy on our site so that we can quote snippets of rules from books verbatim without having companies trying to shut us down.

See our policies on this stuff:

- [What's our policy with answers advocating piracy (accidentally or not)?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/whats-our-policy-with-answers-advocating-piracy-accidentally-or-not/5383#5383)
- [Does this question have too much quoted text?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3084/does-this-question-have-too-much-quoted-text)
- [Are we stepping on D&DI's toes?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/731/are-we-stepping-on-ddis-toes/737#737)

I suggest you subscribe to [D&D Insider](http://ddi.wizards.com/) and use the online character builder.

Comment: Not to mention that it's likely no such thing exists. Adding new content to the offline builder would require decompiling & reverse-engineering the existing modules to see how the content & interactions are structured then hand-coding all of the content in HotFL in that structure, and then hoping you got it all right because debugging will be really, really hard.

Comment: Also, this should be a close reason rather than an answer.

Comment: I suspect we might be able to instruct on how to add content to the thing, _as long as we don't tell them the content._  It's an ok tool. If we can modify the tool's contents, we can add content. If we just tell them "write what's in your book," we're not infringing anything.

Comment: Transforming material (that one has legitimate copies of) for private use isn't piracy (in most jurisdictions), so there's no legal issues involved in this question. If the intented advice is "don't because it's way too much bother, use DDI instead", it would be better to just say that.